# If $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}d^*&-b^*\\-c^*&a^*\end{pmatrix}$ then

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

I want to prove that for a $2\times 2$ matrix $  \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c& d
  \end{pmatrix} $ satisfying
\begin{align}\tag{1}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c& d
  \end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
    d^* & -b^* \\
    -c^* & a^*
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
then 
\begin{align}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c& d
  \end{pmatrix} = e^{i\phi}   \begin{pmatrix}
    A & B \\
    C& D
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
where $\phi,A,B,C,D$ are real and $AD-BC=1$.

---

Starting from 
\begin{align}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c& d
  \end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{ad-bc}   \begin{pmatrix}
    d & -b \\
-    c& a
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
we have 
\begin{align}
  a^* = \frac{a}{ad-bc} \qquad
    b^* = \frac{b}{ad-bc} \qquad 
      c^* = \frac{c}{ad-bc} \qquad 
        d^* = \frac{d}{ad-bc}
\end{align}
but now I got confused.

Apparently I can see that for $a=e^{i\phi}A$, the above relation holds. But I don't know how it derives from $a^*=\frac a{ad-bc}$.

Comment: do you mean by $a^*$ the complex conjugate ?

Comment: equate the coefficients. $a = \frac{a^*}{ad-bc}$ means $\frac{a}{a^*} = ad-bc = e^{2i \phi}$, end of proof

Comment: @GCab, yes i mean $a^*$ is the complex conjugate

Comment: @user1952009, i wonder how one obtain $\frac{a}{a^*}=e^{2i\phi}$.

Comment: $|a/a^*| = 1$ therefore $a / a^* = e^{2 i \phi}$ for some $\phi$ real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} &=
  \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \bar{d} & -\bar{b} \\
    -\bar{c} & \bar{a}
  \end{pmatrix} \\ &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a\bar{d}-b\bar{c} & b\bar{a}-a\bar{b} \\
    c\bar{d}-d\bar{c} & d\bar{a}-c\bar{b}
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Equating "$0$":

> $$
> \left \{
>   \begin{align*}
>     \frac{a}{\bar{a}} &= \frac{b}{\bar{b}} \\
>     \frac{c}{\bar{c}} &= \frac{d}{\bar{d}} \\
>   \end{align*}
> \right.$$

Let $
\left \{
  \begin{align*}
    a &= Ae^{i\theta} \\
    b &= Be^{i\theta}
  \end{align*}
\right.$ and $
\left \{
  \begin{align*}
    c &= Ce^{i\phi} \\
    d &= De^{i\phi}\
  \end{align*}
\right.$ where $A,B,C,D\in \mathbb{R}$

Equating "$1$":

> $$
> \left \{
>   \begin{align*}
>     (AD-BC)e^{i(\theta-\phi)} &= 1 \\
>     (AD-BC)e^{i(\phi-\theta)} &= 1 \\
>   \end{align*}
> \right. $$
>
> $$\implies
> \left \{
>   \begin{align*}
>     AD-BC &= 1 \\
>     \theta &= \phi \\
>   \end{align*}
> \right. $$